# Data member not found error at ara.Range.ListFormat.ListParagraphs(1)

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Sub SetListNumberStyle()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim listPara As Paragraph
    Dim headingFound As Boolean
    
    ' Initialize the flag for heading
    headingFound = False
    
    ' Loop through all paragraphs in the document
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        ' Check if the paragraph has Heading style
        If para.Style Like "Heading*" Then
            ' Set the flag to true when a heading is found
            headingFound = True
        End If
        
        ' Check if the paragraph has List Number style
        If para.Style = "List Number" Then
            ' Convert the paragraph to a ListParagraph
            para.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
            ' Set the starting number to 1
            para.Range.ListFormat.ListParagraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = 1
        End If
        
        ' Reset the flag when a new heading is found
        If headingFound And para.Style Like "Heading*" Then
            headingFound = False
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

I have word document in which I have List Number style and it should be start with 1 and continue till next any heading occur

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.list.cancontinuepreviouslist